# IJCADでActiveDocument.BeginSaveイベントが発生しない

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD 2015の起動・作図・終了をCOM（C#）を使って外部アプリケーションから操作しています。

ところが、以下のイベントが取れないのですが、どこか間違っているのでしょうか？

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    app = new GcadApplication();
    app.Visible = true;
    app.ActiveDocument.BeginSave += new _DGcadDocumentEvents_BeginSaveEventHandler(this.Save);
}

private void Save(string fileName) 
{
    // イベント処理
    //(省略)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

この件、昔開発元に聞いたところ、IJCADの不具合との回答がありました。

.NET APIであれば回避できるとのことでしたので、.NET APIを利用して解決しました。

Comment: CADの不具合なんですね。今回の開発はこぢんまりとしたものなので、Net APIで実現してみることにします。